# Organizing data in NSArray (may be using NSSortDescriptor)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to organize in order this json data...

```
{"message":["Untitled1b","Untitled2b","Untitled3b"],"name":["Untitled1a","Untitled2a","Untitled3a"]}
```

...red in this way...

```
NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath2];  

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:fileContent error:nil];  

// getting the data from inside of "menu"  

//NSString *message = (NSString *) [data objectForKey:@"message"];
 //NSString *name = (NSString *) [data objectForKey:@"name"];

NSArray *messagearray = [data objectForKey:@"message"];
NSArray *namearray    = [data objectForKey:@"name"];


NSDictionary* Dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:messagearray forKeys:namearray];

f = namearray.count;
NSLog(@"happt = %i", f);

//namegroup.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",name, message];

g= 0;

do{

    NSArray *allKeys = [Dictionary allKeys];
    for (int i = 0; i < [allKeys count]; i++) {
        NSString *key = [allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
        NSObject *obj = [Dictionary objectForKey:key];
        // do something
```

As you can see, in the json file message and name (the pair of data) are in the correct order (1a, 1b...). for each pair of data I create 2 text views and display the data. the pairs display correctly, but are mixed up. I mean, I would like them to display in the JSON file order (first 1a, 1b, then 2a, 2b, then 3a, 3b..., not 2a, 2b, then 1a, 1b, then 3a, 3b...)

I tried to use this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"     ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)] autorelease];
[list sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dateSortDescriptor, nil]];
```

...but it did not work!! Please help!!

Comment: Of course your sort descriptor isn't working, because you've asked it to sort `list` (which isn't declared *anywhere in the code you've provided*) based on the key `date` (which isn't used *anywhere in the code you've provided*).

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary` objects are unordered. The order of the keys is usually determined by the most efficient way to search through them, which is unlikely to be the same order in which they were added to the dictionary. In any case, the order of keys in an `NSDictionary` is typically not the order you want them to be in. If you want to sort your keys, you can use:

```
NSDictionary *dict = /* fill your dictionary */;

NSArray *allKeys = [dict allKeys];

NSArray *sortedKeys = [allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

for (NSString *key in sortedKeys)
{
    id value = [dict objectForKey:key];

    // do something with "key" and "value" in sorted order of "key"
}
```

Comment: I did not understand. How do you order with Key sortedinKeys? Can't I just sort data in the order in which it is presented in the json file?

Comment: I tried the above code but it does not make any difference to the order